# java API or framework for queue processing

Tags: java, task-queue

i need an open-source java API or framework for processing items in a queue. i can develop something myself, but do not want to re-invent the wheel (and i don't have much experience in multi-threading). is there such a thing?

the closest solution that i can think of is a business process management (BPM) solution.

right now, i am using multiple Quartz jobs to process the items in my queue. it is not really working out because of scalability and concurrency issues.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you'd want to use an [Executor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)

Comment: An Executor might be used underneath, but it sounds like the poster is asking for a framework/solution for the "larger" problem: some kind of work-flow nonsense :-)

Comment: I dont think so, based on the comment below.  I think they just want to process a bunch of DB rows as fast as possible.

Comment: If multiple Quartz instances are somehow not scalable enough, your out-of-the-box Executors will probably not fare much better.

Comment: chris, well each item has to undergo a sequential process. the catch is this, that each step is resource or computationally intensive. for example, in one step, there is a lot of web crawling. in the following step, there is a lot of data mining. i expect 100's of items per hour queuing up, but at any time, i don't want to be overusing resource or computational power (so maybe 2 web crawling activity concurrently and 1 or 2 data mining processing concurrently).

Comment: Assuming that you don't want to swallow the whole box, back your executor by a pool of two (or whatever) threads.  Build your logic as a series of Runnables, each of which queues the next step.  Add compensation logic as needed.

Comment: Or if you want to have a limited number of each type of activity, use a series of Executors, each of which has a pool of the appropriate size.

Comment: also, i don't think quartz is a very disciplined way to go because essentially, what i need is BPM-ish. but i was questioning to see if there's something out there that would address what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

A queue of what sort?  How many items?  Is Quartz not working out because it's too big or too small?

I'd give some serious thought to using message queues in something like [OpenMQ](http://mq.java.net/).

Comment: it's a queue of items. the queue is composed of rows in database (with a field marking state).

Comment: openmq seems like an ESB (enterprise service bus). that may be an overkill.

Comment: i've seen how some esb's can require extraordinary resource and be a pain on startup (plain old initialization is gruesome). if i can specify a criteria, it'll be light-weight. i'm reading on openmq right now, and the stuff is mostly marketing, so i'm a bit confused on investing some further research time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMS with ActiveMQ and can create optimized queue system as well as ESB. And want to manage workflow based system then ***tpdi*** is right. Use JBoss jbpm.

You can process JMS messages with ThreadPool also. In this case, you can use Executors.

Answer (score 0):

Would the [actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) fit your process?  It's based around the idea of asynchronously passing messages between other actors.  So you can set up a simple state machine to model your process and have all the transitions handled concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine if the problem in is the framework you are using or your code.  I suggest you measure how fast your application is running and how fast your framework will go if its not doing anything at all. (just passing trivial tasks around) You should be able to perform between 100K to 1 million tasks per second using your in process framework. Even using JMS you should be able to achieve 10K messages per second.  If you need to do closer to 10 million tasks per second, I suggest you try grouping your tasks together so each task does more work.

I would be very surprised if your framework was the bottleneck in which case I would suggest using an Executor.

If the framework isn't the cause of your scalability and concurrency issues (which is more likely) you need to restructure your code so it can run for longer periods of time without inter dependencies. i.e. you have to fix your code, a framework won't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is 5 years late, but this might help someone else that has been driven into this question.

Nowadays, there is http://queues.io and it contains a whole lot of queuing (and messaging) frameworks...